# Testing Select element in a react application

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I want to write a test that will check when I change the value of a select element in my react application.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const TimeList =(props) =>{



return(
    <div>
    <label>
      Time
      <br/>
      <select name="lessonTime" value={props.defaultTime} onChange={props.handleChange}>
        <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
        <option value="8:30">8:30</option>
        <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
        <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
        <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
        <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
        <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
        <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
      </select>
    </label>
    </div>
  );

};

export default TimeList;
```

My Test code:

```
it('should select correct time',() =>{
    const mockFunc = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<TimeList value='10:00'
    onChange={mockFunc}/>)
    console.log(wrapper.props());
    wrapper.find('select').simulate('change',{target:{value:'8:00'}});
    expect(wrapper.find('select').props().value).toBe('8:00');
  });
```

The error Im getting is:

```
 Expected value to be (using ===):
      "8:00"
    Received:
      undefined
    
    Difference:
    
      Comparing two different types of values. Expected string but received undefined.
```

It seems I haven't understood how to test the select element.

Any ideas on how to create this kind of test?

Answer (score 8):

You have two problems here:

1. You have a controlled component controlled by the `defaultTime` property. Will never change in your test as the value passed in the props is always the same.
2. The prop should not be called `defaultTime` but `value` (it feels odds to me but that's how it works)

If in your component you change the name of the property as follows:

```
export const TimeList =(props) =>{
  return(
    <div>
      <label>
        Time
        <br/>
        <select name="lessonTime" value={props.value} onChange={props.handleChange}>
          <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
          <option value="8:30">8:30</option>
          <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
          <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
          <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
          <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
          <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
          <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Then at least you can test that, when the component is firstly displayed, the selected value is correct:

```
it('should select correct time',() =>{
  const wrapper = mount(<TimeList value='10:00' onChange={jest.fn()}/>)

  expect(wrapper.find('select').props().value).toBe('10:00')
})
```

In order to test the change of the time you will need to test one level higher (where your state and onChange function is defined).
Look at `TimeListWrapper` in the example below:

```
export const TimeList =(props) =>{
  return(
    <div>
      <label>
        Time
        <br/>
        <select name="lessonTime" value={props.value} onChange={props.handleChange}>
          <option value="8:00">8:00</option>
          <option value="8:30">8:30</option>
          <option value="9:00">9:00</option>
          <option value="10:00">10:00</option>
          <option value="12:00">12:00</option>
          <option value="13:30">13:30</option>
          <option value="19:00">19:00</option>
          <option value="19:30">19:30</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>
  )
}

export class TimeListWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor (props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
      timeListValue: '8:00'
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      timeListValue: event.target.value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TimeList value={this.state.timeListValue} handleChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And this is the test for `TimeListWrapper`:

```
it('should select correct time on change',() =>{
  // When component is mounted
  const wrapper = mount(<TimeListWrapper/>)

  // Then its default value is 8:00
  expect(wrapper.find('select').props().value).toBe('8:00')

  // When 10:00 is selected
  wrapper.find('select').simulate('change', {target: {value: '10:00'}})

  // Then its value changes to 10:00
  expect(wrapper.find('select').props().value).toBe('10:00')
})
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks, that helped me a lot.